# Weighted Conditional Expectation definition in AdaBoost

Tags: expected-value, adaboost

I am looking at "Additive logistic regression a statistical view of boosting" paper ([https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/AdditiveLogisticRegression/alr.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/AdditiveLogisticRegression/alr.pdf))

In page 346, the authors introduce a definition for a weighted expectation. I do not understand the motivation behind this definition and how it is used to get to this result.

It introduces this concept to minimize the following expression:

[image]

Can someone explain the idea behind this please?

Thank you